# Having a views result in raw output

Tags: views, 7

I already found [Get "Raw" views data (with no or little markup)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/get-raw-views-data-with-no-or-little-markup), but it wasn't, what I was looking for. I really do need the raw fields for having them differently styled in a module. Because the view itself should just be styled like it is, when navigating to it as page. But my module should be able to read the fields in raw-style. Or do I have to clone a view in order to be able to read the raw format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module can load and execute the view itself. You can get the results from the view without changing the display.

```
// Load the view
$myview = views_get_view('my_view');
// Set arguments if you need to
$myview->set_arguments(array($code));
// Execute the query
$myview->execute();        
// Loop over the results
foreach ($myview->result as $row) {
  // The fields are properties of the row
  $x = $row->my_field;
}
```